# What chemicals are mixed together to cause chemoluminescence?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, photochemistry

My brother is supposed to do a science experiment at school for an open house. We found an interesting experiment in which you pour several chemicals together, causing the resulting concoction to glow brightly. You can make several colors in this way. Then you can dump them together, to demonstrate how white light is made up of several colors mixed together. Several questions.
1. Which chemicals are used?
2. How do you get the colors?
3. Where can you buy the chemicals you need?

Comment: "Where can you buy the chemicals you need?" Looks off-topic

Comment: I second what @Mithoron said. Also, as written, it's pretty broad. If you can narrow your query - what colors? what procedure(s) are you interested in investigating? - that will help us help you.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35527/how-do-things-glow-in-the-dark https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14241/is-there-anything-funny-i-can-do-with-chemicals-in-glowsticks

Answer (score 0):

If you want different colours, you might want to give the **peroxyoxalate reaction**, known from *glow sticks*, a try.

Typically, you will need three components:

1. a diaryl oxalate
2. hydrogen peroxide (to oxidize the diaryl oxalate, probably to a 1,2-dioxetanedione)
3. a fluorescent dye, which determines the final colour.

[Wilhelm J. Baader](http://www2.iq.usp.br/docente/?id=wjbaader) has examined the reaction in great detail, and you'll find a lot of references on his website.